# Forcing Specific Format in Input Field While Typing with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to prevent the use of any other format than formally correct percentages in a field, while any other input would simply not be shown even though a keystroke was executed.

Right now I have the following code which does not allow me to achieve my result:

```
$("input").keypress(function (e) {
var regex = /\d{1,4}\.?\d{0,3}/g;
var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
}
});
```

While there are many options to validate ex post, e.g. with a button, I would really like to have it on-the-fly, as the user types. However, this expression does not even allow me to insert a decimal point after the first digit(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a JS dev (comments are welcome!), but right now you are testing your regex against the single key so only digit keys are allowed.

Assuming you want to allow only numbers with 1-4 digits, possibly followed by a `.` and up to three digits, you can use the regex:

```
/^\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{0,3})?$/
```

`(?:...)` is a non capturing group and `^$` are anchors matching beginning and end of the string. Be aware that this form also allows ending `.` (like `1234.`).

In JS code, this gives (see [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jj24/)):

```
var regex = /^\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{0,3})?$/;
$("input").keypress(function (e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (!regex.test($("input").val() + key)) {
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Because @Robins function helped me a lot, but prevents keycodes like Left, Right, Delete, ... here is a slight update for line 4: `if ((!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode) > 0 && !regex.test($("input").val() + key)) {`

Comment: Thank solved. But I want my first digit to be non zero. Because my input field is for price. And price could not be start with 0. What will be the regex for this case?

Comment: @ImZedi `\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]` so you can replace the first one with `[1-9]\d{0-3}`

Comment: @Robin thanks for responding. I have tried this but it will Ok if I test whole string. Test will true if pattern matches. But problem is with typing i.e. If I enter first digit, my string will not have second digit so test fill false. So I am not able to typing anything. Please can you tell me how overcome this?

Comment: @ImZedi If you replace `^\d{1,4}` with `^[1-9]\d{0-3}` it should test true on a string that is only one digit long. If that doesn't work please create another question on stackoverflow, it will be easier to explain your problem and get answers :-)