# Live regex test while typing

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I want to make a html form, where input fields are live checked for their pattern and disable wrong keys.
Like the pattern says `https?://.+`, i want a valid check if the user types in
 `h` then `ht` then `htt` etc.
the problem is, that the regex will search for the complete pattern and will return false.
I alreayd tried to change it into
`var regex = new RegExp( $el.val() );
console.log( $attr.required.match( regex ) );`
while `$attr.required` was `https?://` but this will only work, if my required attribute is not regex string

Someone knows how to do this?
I need this for my work

Comment: You can use the ng-pattern attribute to add a regex to a field.

Comment: Try looking at this QA: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488352/forcing-specific-format-in-input-field-while-typing-with-regular-expression)

Comment: Try this regex, but I am not sure you are on the right track: `^(?:h|ht{1,2}|https?|https?:\/{0,2}|https?:\/\/[^\/].*)$` ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT3eF7/1))

Comment: Reverse the process while the user is not finished, match the input to the regex. Once the user enters the dot after // you simply accept if the previous value was true.

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr: this will work on normal progress, but i need in this case not only string characters but a specific order of characters typed in. ...@ stribizhev: tha would be a way, but on long words it will be a kilometer of regex string, like it shoulb be a valid youtube url.... @ShellFish: thats what i did before, but then i cannot check for https?, because the user has to typein a `?` But thanks to all of you. More answers/suggests are wished :)

Comment: What exactly do you care about here? You want for sure to have HTTP:// with anything afterwards regardless of length? and maybe HTTP with an S optional. Is this all correct?

Comment: Yes, but dont hang up on http its like any regex with some letterns .. only expressions is easdy, and i also managed dates but not regex with real letters...